# Check winner in a Tic Tac Toe game

Tags: c#, game, array, hash-map

I have the below code to check for a winner in a Tic Tac Toe game.  I'm wondering if this is a good approach, and if there is a better way of doing this (maybe by monitoring the state of the board).

```
public void CheckWinner()
{
    var board = GameBoard.Content;//stores data as dictionary
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        int a = winningIndex[i, 0], b = winningIndex[i, 1], c = winningIndex[i, 2];

        if (board.ContainsKey(a) && board.ContainsKey(b) && board.ContainsKey(c))
        {
            Func<KeyValuePair<int, string>, bool> containsO = input => (input.Key == a || input.Key == b || input.Key == c) && input.Value == "O";

            Func<KeyValuePair<int, string>, bool> containsX = input => (input.Key == a || input.Key == b || input.Key == c) && input.Value == "X";

            var oResult = board.Where(containsO).ToDictionary();
            if (oResult.Count == 3)
            {
                Winner = Player.Computer;
                WinnerIndex = oResult.Keys.ToArray();
                _gameOver = true;
            }

            var xResult = board.Where(containsX).ToDictionary();
            if (xResult.Count == 3)
            {
                Winner = Player.Human;
                WinnerIndex = xResult.Keys.ToArray();
                _gameOver = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (board.Count == 9)
    {
        _gameOver = true;
        Winner = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an approach to checking TicTacToe winners that I don't think I have seen before. Because of this, I'm not quite sure how `GameBoard.Content` and `winningIndex` are structured. Could you provide some additional information about that? What values exists in `winningIndex` and how do you add those values there? What kind of dictionary is your board? (I got a feeling it's `<int, String>`, right?) Do you fill it as each tile is played? (I assume yes?)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg The type of `containsO` confirms your guess about the dictionary. My guess is `winningIndex` would look like `new int[,] { { 0, 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8 }, { 0, 3, 6 }, { 1, 4, 7 }, { 2, 5, 8 }, { 0, 4, 8 }, { 6, 4, 2 } }`.

Answer (score 8):

General advice:

- Use enums instead of strings for board squares. This will protect you against mistakes like `board[i] = "x"`.
- A dictionary is overkill for a 3x3 board, you can just use an array. One benefit is that a bad index will throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException`, while a dictionary will not complain.
- Board logic should be encapsulated in a class, so that you can make changes to your implementation (like switching from a dictionary to an array) without the rest of your code having to change. It will also allow you to guard against errors such as overwriting a non-empty board square.

To make the function easier to test:

- Pass the board to the function, or make this a method of your Board class, instead of referring to `GameBoard.Content`.
- Return an object representing the game state, instead of modifying private fields.

Together, it might look like this:

```
public static GameState GetGameState(Board board)
{
    foreach (var winningLine in WinningLines)
    {
        var line = new BoardState[]
        {
            board[winningLine[0]],
            board[winningLine[1]],
            board[winningLine[2]]
        };

        if (line.All(state => state == BoardState.Human))
        {
            return GameState.HumanWon(winningLine);
        }

        if (line.All(state => state == BoardState.Computer))
        {
            return GameState.ComputerWon(winningLine);
        }
    }

    return board.Any(state => state == BoardState.Empty)
        ? GameState.Unfinished
        : GameState.Tie;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

These variable initializations are not very readable nor maintainable as a single line:

> ```
> int a = winningIndex[i, 0], b = winningIndex[i, 1], c = winningIndex[i, 2];
> ```

Have each one on a separate line:

```
int a = winningIndex[i, 0];
int b = winningIndex[i, 1];
int c = winningIndex[i, 2];
```

Moreover, you should use descriptive variable names instead of using single letters.  *You* may know what they mean (for some time at least), but *anyone else* reading your code may not.